# How to align 16-bit ints for use with SSE intrinsics

Tags: c, sse, simd, memory-alignment, sse2

I am working with two-dimensional arrays of 16-bit integers defined as

```
int16_t e[MAX_SIZE*MAX_NODE][MAX_SIZE];
int16_t C[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
```

Where `Max_SIZE` and `MAX_NODE` are constant values. I'm not a professional programmer, but somehow with the help of people in StackOverflow I managed to write a piece of code that deploys SSE instruction on my data and achieved a significant speed-up. Currently, I am using the intrinsics that do not require data alignment (mainly `_mm_loadu_si128` and `_mm_storeu_si128`).

```
for (b=0; b<n; b+=8){
    v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&C[level][b]); // level defined elsewhere.
    v2 = _mm_loadu_si128((__m128i*)&e1[node][b]); // node defined elsewhere.
    v3 = _mm_and_si128(v1,v2);
    _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&C[level+1][b],v3);
}
```

When I change the intrinsics to their counterparts for aligned data (i.e. `_mm_load_si128` and `_mm_store_si128`), I get run-time errors, which leads me to the assumption that my data is not aligned properly.

My question is now, if my data is not aligned properly, how can I align it to be able to use the corresponding intrinsics? I'd think since the integers are 16 bits, they're automatically aligned. But I seem to be wrong!

Any insight on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSE needs data to be aligned on 16 *bytes* boundary, not 16 *bits*, that's your problem.

What you're looking for to align your static arrays is compiler dependent.

If you're using MSVC, you'll have to use [`__declspec(align(16))`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/83ythb65.aspx), or with GCC, this would be [`__attribute__((aligned (16)))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html).

Comment: Note that allocating a `__declspec(align(16))` structure with `malloc` or `new` is not guaranteed to get you something aligned to 16 bytes, so you'll need to be very careful where you use those. It may be better to use `posix_memalign` (in POSIX) or `_aligned_malloc` (in VC++).

Comment: `__declspec(align(16))` worked fine for me. I'll look into `_aligned_malloc` also. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there a way to define a Macro which will be portable between MSVC and GCC? Thank You.